# Passing Ruby interpreter arguments with hashbang command

Tags: ruby, shebang

I am using the following hashbang command with my RVM installation. How do I pass the `-w` argument to the ruby interpreter?

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend setting the `RUBYOPT` environment variable.  In this manner, you don't have to edit your executables.

```
RUBYOPT="-w $RUBYOPT"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this reference](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/96121) you can use a separate declaration outside of the shebang for that:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
$VERBOSE=true
```