# Ruby script from the bash

Tags: ruby, bash

Let suppose I wrote the ruby script and I want to run it by my user at every path, just like a usual command.

What I need to do to implement this option?

IE I run this command like this:

```
ruby mp3split -argument1 s
```

Now I need to have this command everywhere as one user:

```
mp3split -argument s
```

Comment: If I get the question right, I think the PATH variable is what you are looking for. I'd suggest you to google for it, there are tons of places where this is explained. In short in your terminal do `echo $PATH` to get the list of paths where you should put you script, or add a new location (with your script to the PATH, `export PATH=$PATH:/your/new/path`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the hashbang line at a very top of your ruby file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and make your ruby script executable:

```
chmod +x mp3split
```

Now you might try to run it with

```
/path/to/your/script/mp3split ...
```

To be able to run it w/out the necessity to specify the full path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/script
```

Put the line above somewhere in the `.bashrc` or `.profile` to make it persistent between sessions.

**NB** Besides the above, you might find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460206/passing-ruby-interpreter-arguments-with-hashbang-command) interesting.